# How to make a milestone invisibile in trac

Tags: trac

Is it possible to make a milestone invisible in `trac 0.11` ?
I have found custom python modules which are a starting point for doing so but none of them worked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trac 0.11. is quite out-of-date by now. You'll find a large number of plugins no longer support it. What I'm going to suggest will most likely work in Trac 0.11, but if you encounter bugs then you may have to upgrade to get them resolved.

Where would you like to hide the milestone? If you'd like to hide it from the milestone menu on the ticket form, that is easy - once the milestone is closed it will be hidden from all users that don't have `TICKET_ADMIN` or `TRAC_ADMIN` permission.

If you would like the milestone to be hidden from the roadmap, all links to the milestone rendered as disabled, and the milestone not view-able when navigating to the URL `/milestone/<milestone name>`, you can use the [fine-grained permissions module](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions). You can hide the milestone by elevating the permissions that are required to view the module. For example,

```
[milestone:milestone1]
* = MILESTONE_ADMIN
```

would hide the milestone from users that don't have `MILESTONE_ADMIN`.

In Trac 0.11, the module fine-grained permissions module is [/sample-plugins/permissions/authz_policy.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-0.11/sample-plugins/permissions/authz_policy.py) (it was moved to `/tracopt` in later releases). [FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin) provides a web interface for editing the authz file.

Comment: you mean `* = !MILESTONE_ADMIN` ? That worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, the configuration I listed was incorrect. `* = !MILESTONE_VIEW` would be sensible as well.

Comment: I ended up displaying the milestone only to authenticated users. Thanks for your help. This are the two lines for doing so: `authenticated = MILESTONE_VIEW` and `* = !MILESTONE_VIEW`